# Javascript > PHP (learning)

Tags: javascript, php

I realize I am most likely going to get flamed for this question but with nobody to ask, I turn to you. Would this be a proper javascript > php conversion - before I start bad practices, I want to know if this is the correct way to go about this.

JAVASCRIPT --

```
Baseline.prototype.setAge = /*void*/ function(/*double*/ newage) {
    if ((newage > 0.0) && (newage <= 250.0)) {
        this.Age = newage;
    }
```

PHP --

```
public function setAge($newage) {
    if (($newage > 0.0) && ($newage <= 250.0))
    {
        $Age = $newage;
    }
```

Thanks for the help everyone - just trying to keep on learning.

Comment: What do you mean by " javascript > php conversion"?

Comment: You could use `Baseline.prototype.setAge = /*void*/ function setAge(/*double*/ newage) {` to keep the function name. Other than that, yeah, the two functions seem to do the same thing.

Comment: This question shouldn't get _flamed_.  It's on topic, and provides an attempt.  So, good job.

Answer (score 6):

The correct php snippet would be:

```
class Baseline
{
    public $age;

    public function setAge($newage)
    {
        if (($newage > 0.0) && ($newage <= 250.0)) {
            $this->age = $newage;
        }
    }
}
```

Your current snippet assigns $newage to a variable that is scoped to the function, effectively doing nothing.

Comment: You should declare $age before you use it

Comment: Thank you, That is best practice of course, but it would work regardless :)

Comment: In the JavaScript example `this.age` wasn't set previously anyways.  Sure it's good practice, but it still followed a more valid conversion without the declaration.  I guess the more help the merrier?

Comment: Ah ok that does make way more sense seeing is that way - was not sure if '->' pointed to new ownership. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure I got this.. How does this one look and thank again, you are all the best source of knowledge ever.

JSCRIPT
`Baseline.prototype.getNewAct = /*double*/ function(/*Intervention*/ inter) {
    act = inter.getAct(this);
    return act;
}`



PHP
`public function getNewAct($inter) {
            $act = $inter->getAct($this);
            return $act;
    }`
Thanks again everyone!!

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. The arrow (->) means you are accessing an objects instance variables.